# Where to find the OSB Business service configuration details in the underlying database?

Tags: osb

In OSB Layer when the endpoint uri is changed, I need to alert the core group that the endpoint has changed and to review it. I tried SLA Alert rules but it does not have options for it. My question is, the endpoint uri should be saved somewhere in the underlying database. If so what is the schema and the table name to query it.

Comment: Can't you make a script that sends an alert when you are deploying with a new endpoint? How do you deploy?

Answer (score 1):

URI or in fact any other part of OSB artifact is not stored in relational database but rather kept in memory in it's original XML structure. It can be only accessed thru dedicated session management API. Interfaces you will need to use are part o com.bea.wli.sb.management.configuration and com.bea.wli.sb.management.query packages. Unfortunately it is not as straightforward as it sounds, in short, to extract URI information you will need to:

1. Create session instance(SessionManagementMBean)
2. Obtain ALSBConfigurationMBean instance that operates on SessionManagementMBean
3. Create Query object instance(BusinessServiceQuery) an run it on ALSBConfigurationMBean to get ref object to osb artifact of your interest
4. Invoke getServiceDefinition on your ref object to get XML service
   definition
5. Extract URI from XML service definition with XPath

Downside of this approach is that you are basically pooling configuration each time you want to check if anything has changed.

More information including JAVA/WLST examples can be found in [Oracle Fusion Middleware Java API Reference for Oracle Service Bus](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28280_01/apirefs.1111/e15033/com/bea/wli/sb/management/configuration/package-summary.html)

There is also a good blog post describing OSB customization with WLST [ALSB/OSB customization using WLST](http://www.theserverlabs.com/blog/?p=926)

Answer (score 0):

The information about services and all its properties can be obtained [via Java API](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/osb/java-api/index.html?com/bea/wli/sb/management/configuration/ALSBConfigurationMBean.html). The API documentation contains sample code, so you can get it up and running quite quickly, see the *Querying resources* paragraph when following the given link.

We use the API to read the service (both proxy and business) configuration and for simple management.

As long as you only read the properties you do not need to handle management sessions. Once you change the values, you need to start a session and activate it once you are done -- a very similar approach to Service bus console.